# How to make a curtain

Tags: add-on

In the addon ArchiMesh there is a Japaneses curtain feature, but, it looks straight and does not have the fold that I want in it. Is there an addon that can do this for me? If not, how can I make a curtain (like in the images below)?

[image: curtain sample image1]
[image: curtain sample image 2]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no add on that makes  curtains for you the way you describe. You have to model the fabric yourself. You might find [this tutorial](https://cgcookie.com/archive/modeling-with-cloth-simulation-in-blender/) helpful.

Comment: @Timaroberts u said its tutorial but there is a download link where is the tutorial

Comment: The tutorial is part of Blender Cookie's archive, and they are not streaming the content anymore but have kept it available for download.

Comment: its some 235mb download what is in that file contains to heavy file

Comment: @atek You need them for animation or still image?

Comment: @LukeD still image only

Comment: @atek I'll create an answer in a while. With simple plane modeling.

Comment: @LukeD thanks hope it will quick and easily method. If you show the the tie at one end as seen in the image will be more helpful thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Final result:

[image]

1. Add a *Plane*, scale it as you need, go to *Edit Mode*, subdivide it couple of times - <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide* and select vertices as shown below.

[image: 1]

2. Go to *Top Ortho view* and move selected vertices along choosen axis.

[image: 2]

3. Go back to *Front view* select top edge and in *Object Data tab*, under *Vertex Groups* add new *Group* (+ sign), and *Assign* selected vertices.

[image: 3]

4. Go to *Object mode* and add *Cloth physics* to the plane in *Physics tab*. Check *Pinning* and select *Group*. Select preset *Silk* and enable *Self Collision* (*Quality* > 2, *Distance* > 0.6) under *Cloth Collision* group.

[image: 4]

5. Create stripe to tie the curtains and make it wider than curtains. I've used simple *torus* in this example. Go to *Physics tab* and set it to *Collision*. Set *Outer* and Inner values to the lowest (0.001).

[image: 5]

6. Animate scale of the tie. I've putted two keyframes, first frame and 50. Scale by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: 6]

That's it. You can add *Subsurf* to the plane to make it more smoother and add *Crease* around whole plane with it. Also you will need to modify the tie using proportional editing and make it more stick to the curtains.

You can apply *Cloth modifier* and reuse them as you want.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Yep: this is a good explanation of a pretty standard technique. you can also do this with other deformations. For example, if you want the "curtains pulled to the side" look classically shown at theatre stages, just animate a loop or bar pulling them to the side.