# How to make pencil pleat curtains

Tags: vertices

Anyone have any idea how to make pencil pleat curtains? The problem I'm having is that the pleat at the top of the curtain is random thicknesses and shapes. Like this. Would it be a case of modelling the curtain and then running some kind of cloth simulation as though a drawstring is pulling it together?

[image]

Comment: I think some kind of visualisation would be helpful to make your problem clear.

Comment: Maybe this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71721/how-to-make-a-curtain/71727#71727

Comment: Something like this https://www.johnlewis.com/john-lewis-barathea-pair-blackout-lined-pencil-pleat-curtains/p1926244