# How to make folded sails?

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and i am currently modeling a pirate ship and i would like to make folded sails like the one in the picture.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Sculpting, simulation (did you see any curtain tutorials)? Pls show your results so we can see the problem you are having and guide you from there.

Comment: No i have not tried any simulation or sculpting type soutions. The only thing i tried was adding a cylinder add some loop cuts and then move vertices or edges around, but the result was not very good looking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer that solved my problem. I followed the answer in this post:

[How to make a curtain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71721/how-to-make-a-curtain)

Comment: or you could simulate it with a Texture node like this (quickly made), it depends if it used for closeup shots: https://zupimages.net/up/18/28/tzvs.jpg