# Why am I getting magnetic effects from cloth objects?

Tags: physics

Using the current Blender version, 2.8 RC2. This setup was according to another posting I followed to learn how to create curtains and get a pulled back/curtain ring effect.

For the most part it works as designed; however instead of just cinching the curtains, the torus attracts them. Eventually the curtains get all wrapped around the thing. Magnetic forces are not turned on for anything.

I can't find anything else that would cause one object to be pulled in to the other. A little help please.

[image]

Original post, with Blender file I downloaded, is here:

[How to make a curtain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71721/how-to-make-a-curtain)

Comment: Might be wrong about this, but could it be that the cloth is configured to be very stiff causing it to crumple almost like paper?

Comment: Example blend from linked answer works as advertised. If you [share your file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/630/935) someone may find what you are missing in your file.

Comment: What appeared to be the issue is the "Single Sided" option in Collision settings. Somewhere along the way I unchecked that, which made the cloth try and wrap around the ring. It's confusing since it looks magnetic, which can be set elsewhere.

Comment: @SamVimes - please add this as an answer so you can mark it as Accepted so that others can learn from your experience.

Comment: @RichSedman Will do... I wasn't 100% sure that was the answer, but in lieu of other replies appears to be the case.

Comment: @SamVimes The only other things I would suggest would be to ensure you've 'Applied Scale' to all interacting meshes and make sure your collision bounds aren't set too high on the ring. Check that it isn't Self Collision issues also, by disabling self-collision. Also, ensure your mesh is made of approximately square faces - rather than elongated rectangles or triangles - that can help get realistic cloth behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appeared to be the issue is the "Single Sided" option in Collision settings. Somewhere along the way I unchecked that, which made the cloth try and wrap around the ring. It's confusing since it looks magnetic, which can be set elsewhere.